# How to display the value of a variable within javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I want to trap and alert or echo the value of var thisCount
The problem is I can't display the value.I'd tried many ways but no luck.

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function () {

   var thisCount = $(this).data('count');

   //this place the code

   $(".modal-body #count").val( thisCount);
});
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] and learn how to use the code formatting features of the Stackoverflow editors.

Comment: you could use `.html()`

Comment: `alert(value)` ??

Comment: two of the three lines of code you have shown us appear to use jquery, yet you have made no mention of it in your question.

Comment: provide your html

Comment: @symcbean that's all jquery, none of it is not.

Comment: So it is - its worse than I thot :O

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't really clarified what you've tried or where you want the value displayed, but common answers are:

1) Console. This will output to your browsers log.

```
console.log(thisCount);
```

2) If you want to put it into an HTML tag, you can use classic javascript

```
document.getElementById('yourTagsId').innerHTML += thisCount; 
// You can use = instead of += as well
```

3) You could also use an alert or a confirm

```
alert(thisCount);

confirm(thisCount, function(){return true;});
// confirm takes both a displayed value, and a function which will be performed when the user presses the 'Ok' button
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should verify if the jquery library is properly imported
Also, you can use the Chrome Developer tools (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>i</kbd>) and verify the value in the javascript console. Just to see if you can see the value in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you need ah `data`attribute like this below .`alert` `console.log` both are working

```js
$(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function () {

   var thisCount = $(this).data('count');

   $("#count").val( thisCount);
  console.log(thisCount)
  alert(thisCount)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="open-dialog" data-count="hello">click</button>
<input type="text" id="count">
```